# Liouville's Criterion and Integration of $\sin(z)/z$ using elementary functions

Tags: integration, complex-integration, elementary-functions

**Liouville's Criterion:** $\int fe^g$ is elementary iff there is rational function $q$ in $\mathbb{C}(z)$ such that $$f=q'+qg'$$ where $f\neq0$ and $g$ is a non constant function in $\mathbb{C}(z)$.

Now using this fact: How should I proceed to prove that $\int \dfrac{\sin z}{z}dz$ cannot be written using elementary functions?

Comment: Hint: try multiplying by a clever form of $1$ ($e^{-z}e^z$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see why the antiderivative of $\sin(z)/z$ cannot be written using elementary functions, consult:

> Rosenlicht, M. (1972). *Integration in finite terms*. American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 79, No. 9 (Nov., 1972), pp. 963-972. [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318066), [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=Rosenlicht+Integration+finite+terms)

Liouville's Theorem is used at the end of the paper to show precisely the fact about which you have asked. Here is an excerpt:

[image]